# How to query MongoDb document with key names that have whitespace via Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm totally new to node and mongodb (db in general)...
I'm working with a handful of developers to get an app going and I am running into trouble querying a mongoDB collection that's been set up for me.

Our app is on heroku and we are using an online db through MongoLab.
The collection I need to query looks like this:

`{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59c5c6ed25ed60c204bf0741"
    },
    "O*NET-SOC Code": "11-1011.00",
    "Title": "Chief Executives",
    "Element ID": "2.A.1.a",
    "Element Name": "Reading Comprehension",
    "Scale ID": "IM",
    "Scale Name": "Importance",
    "Data Value": 4.12,
    "N": 8,
    "Standard Error": 0.13,
    "Lower CI Bound": 3.88,
    "Upper CI Bound": 4.37,
    "Recommend Suppress": "N",
    "Not Relevant": "",
    "Date": "07/2014",
    "Domain Source": "Analyst"
}`

Since we are using Mongoose and I have not received any defined Mongoose Schema for this document, my guess is that I need to set up the schema myself to use Mongoose to query -- but how do I do this? The object keys for the db have whitespace and I have tried a couple different ways to define the schema but no matter what I do, I get `null` returned for my query search.

I feel like the issue is coming from an ill definition of the schema b/c my query syntax works fine when I'm working with another collection where the keys are just one word i.e. { myName : String }.

Am I missing something here? I also read that Mongoose is like the front-end of MongoDB; if I were to totally skip Mongoose and query the DB already set up on heroku/mLab, how would I do this?

I apologize if the question is very basic. I'm totally new to being a dev :X

Thanks in advance!

---

edit: Here is what I tried

`models/skill.js`

```
'use strict';                                          

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// define new moongoose Schema
var skillsSchema = new Schema({
    "O*NET-SOC Code": String,
    "Title": String,
    "Element ID": String,
    "Element Name": String,
    "Scale ID": String,
    "Scale Name": String,
    "Data Value": Number,
    "N": Number,
    "Standard Error": Number,
    "Lower CI Bound": Number,
    "Upper CI Bound": Number,
    "Recommend Suppress": String,
    "Not Relevant": String,
    "Date": String,
    "Domain Source": String
});

// compile to model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Skill', skillsSchema);
```

`lib/helper.js`

```
var Skill = require('../models/skill.js');
function findSkill () {
    Skill.findOne({ 'Element ID': '2.A.1.a'}, function (err, skill) {
        console.log(skill) // always logs null
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you get back when you run that query through another client, e.g. Robomongo?

Comment: What does `Skill.findOne({'Element ID': { '$exists': True }})` return?

Comment: @jmcgui05 it returns null.. is there a possibility that the DB might not be set up correctly?

Comment: So I have a similar query like this: `db.collection.findOne({"myKey 1": {$exists: true}})` which returns results. When I change it to `db.collection.findOne({"myKey 12": {$exists: true}})`, which I know does not exist, it returns null. I'd say first, retry the previous command but remove quotes from `$exists` and `True` to lowercase. If that does not work, I'd remove the query restrictor and just query for all skills like this: `db.collection.find().pretty()` which will return all results. Bear in mind, I have not used Mongoose to query the db directly, but I don't think your issue is Mongoose

Comment: To be clear, change your function to query like this using Mongoose and see what you get back: `Skill.find({}, function (err, skill) {`